# Alternative image sizes are too large

Tags: images, compression

Very new to WordPress here so still learning a lot so if anything I say here is silly then please go easy on me

On a site I've created I'm using this plugin here :

https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-image-sizes/

I believe I'm hopefully correct in saying that this is basically allowing me to create smaller images from the main uploaded image in exactly the same way it would as defining the sizes in the functions.php file?

I'm not one much for working without a graphical interface so prefer this way of working wherever possible.

Anyway I'm not sure if I'm making some sort of rookie mistake as I've made an image size which is smaller than the uploaded image and where the image is being used *(currently being output by a Beaver Builder module)* it is indeed being spat out at the correct pixel size however it is a very large image, around **450kb** whereby if I download the image to my computer and run it through **Image Optim (OSX)** then it comes down to around **65kb** which is waaaaayyy better as you can imagine. I've got about 6 of these images on one page and so as you can see the page size is very very bloated.

Is there something I've missed as to why WordPress is only resizing the images but it's not compressing them or is everything doing its job correctly and there's something else I need to do / install in order to compress images too?

I thought I'd read that WordPress did compress images but I may have misread that somewhere?

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Best wishes,

Mark

Comment: From the reviews of the linked plugin "An excellent plugin but is no longer updated and can be abandoned by its author. ". Did you try any [image optimization plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/compress/)?

Comment: Hi kero. Thanks for the reply. Yes I'm currently looking into optimisation plugins but was just wondering does WordPress not have anything at all built in for optimisation or is everything actually working the way it should be? The images are resizing to the correct pixel dimensions so the plugin is definitely working fine in that sense but I'm just wondering if they should be getting any sort of compression at all or whether WordPress just doesn't handle that part of things at all? Thanks.

Comment: To be honest I don't know much about how WP handles images. What I know, handling images (be it resizing, cropping, ...) is not trivial, and it seems the author of the plugin did something which causes the results to be huge in size